# Changing File Extenstion - TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple

Tags: python

Ive got a question about why im getting a TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple; in the line, os.rename(self.root.filenameMOD, fileBASE + '.wav').

Below is the snippet of code that this error reguards.

```
    def importFileMOD(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.root.filenameMOD = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = '/',title = 'Select file',filetypes = (('wav files','*.wav'), ('mp3 files', '*.mp3'), ("all files","*.*")))
        MODnamebase = os.path.basename(self.root.filenameMOD)
        MODnameEXT = os.path.splitext(self.root.filenameMOD)[1]
        print(MODnameEXT)
        global MODname
        MODname = os.path.splitext(MODnamebase)[0]
        global fileMOD
        if MODnameEXT == '.wav':
            fileMOD = self.root.filenameMOD
            self.lblLocCMod.configure(text=fileMOD)
        elif MODnameEXT == '.mp3':
            fileBASE = os.path.splitext(self.root.filenameMOD)
            os.rename(self.root.filenameMOD, fileBASE + '.wav')
            fileMOD = self.root.filenameMOD
            self.lblLocCMod.configure(text=fileMOD)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function `os.path.splitext()` returns a tuple, containing the path of the file without the file extension in the first position of the tuple, and the extension in the second one. (You probably already knew this because you treated the return value of the function as it should in this line: -> `MODname = os.path.splitext(MODnamebase)[0]`)

Nevertheless, what you're trying to do in this line -> `os.rename(self.root.filenameMOD, fileBASE + '.wav')` is wrong because (as the message of the exception you received says), you're attempting to concatenate that tuple with the string `'.wav'`.

Perhaps what you meant was:

```
os.rename(self.root.filenameMOD, fileBASE[0] + '.wav')
```